# Delete an item from a JavaScript set

Tags: javascript, set

How to delete an item from a set with condition

```
if(item.id === 2){
   mySet.delete(item)
}
```

I can't use `mySet.has(item)` because only common thing in the objects is the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you already have a reference to the object, you'll have to iterate through the Set's values to `.find` the matching object, then call `.delete` with it:

```js
const set = new Set([
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
]);

const obj = [...set].find(obj => obj.id === 2);
set.delete(obj);
console.log([...set]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create array of remaining items like

```
var resultArr = [];    
yourobj.forEach((item,index)=>{ 
        if(item.id === 2)
        {
          // nothing
        }  
        else
        {
            resultArr.push(item);
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement to locate and delete matching items from a set according to your conditions.  And in case you are concerned, [it's ok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28306768/1563833) to delete an item from a set while iterating.

```js
let mySet = new Set([
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 }
]);

for (const item of mySet) if (item.id == 2) { mySet.delete(item); /*optional*/ break; }
console.log([...mySet]);
```

If there are multiple matching items, you can omit the `break` in this example.

Answer (score -1):

similar immutable way to do this in one line:

```
const result = mySet.filter(x => x.id === 2);
```

Comment: Did you try that? (`Set` does not define `filter`)